# How to control for a known relatedness matrix (Mixed model)

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model

I would like to fit a regression model but adding the genetic relatedness matrix (GRM; n x n matrix) to control for the association of the sample.

I am not sure what is the best package to do that. I have found the function glmkin but I am not able to obtain fit statistics. Please see this example:

```
require(GMMAT)
data(example)
attach(example)
model0 <- glmmkin(disease ~ age + sex, data = pheno, kins = GRM, id = "id",
                  family = binomial(link = "logit"))
model0$theta
model0$coefficients
model0$cov


model1 <- glmmkin(disease ~ age , data = pheno, kins = GRM, id = "id",
                  family = binomial(link = "logit"))
model1$theta
model1$coefficients
model1$cov
```

I would like to fit a full model and then compare restricted models. However, I do not knwo how to get fit statistics (AIC, R2 and if possible P values) from these models.

The only information I get using summary(model0) is:

```
> summary(model0)
                  Length Class  Mode   
theta                  2 -none- numeric
n.pheno                1 -none- numeric
n.groups               1 -none- numeric
coefficients           3 -none- numeric
linear.predictors    400 -none- numeric
fitted.values        400 -none- numeric
Y                    400 -none- numeric
X                   1200 -none- numeric
P                 160000 -none- numeric
residuals            400 -none- numeric
scaled.residuals     400 -none- numeric
cov                    9 -none- numeric
Sigma_i                0 -none- NULL   
Sigma_iX               0 -none- NULL   
converged              1 -none- logical
call                   6 -none- call   
id_include           400 -none- numeric
```

I have tried using:

```
anova(model0, model1)
```

but it says:

```
Error in UseMethod("anova") : 
  no applicable method for 'anova' applied to an object of class "glmmkin"
```

How can I get fit statistics when using the glmmkin function and compare models? is it possible?

I would be particularly grateful if you could let me know what is the best method to do this. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Questions about how to apply method X using R package Y are off-topic on Cross Validated. Please edit your question to emphasize the general statistical questions you'd like to ask.